# how to get value of a div field in a jsp

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I want to get div value in a jsp and print it. so basically i have a code that looks like this

```
<td class = 'modelercol cellHeaderMultiviewString CellWithComment'>
                    <div id="desc" class="preserveText" style="margin-top: 0px;margin-bottom: 0px;"></div>
                <i want to write code here to print the value of **desc**>
                </td>
```

The value of div desc i am setting in a js code something like this:--

```
function setFieldTexts()
{

$("#desc").text("hello");
}
```

my question is how to get the same value in a jsp page.

[image]

as you can see in the picture when i click on the dropdown of the column Variable the java script function setFieldTexts is called. on call of the java script function what exactly it is doing is it is setting the div id=**desc** .. so my requirement is that i want to write a jsp function inside the  so that i can print the value of the id desc..

Comment: You can't get value from div using jsp code. That value should be input field . Also , for getting it in jsp(server code) you need to submit it to server .

Comment: @Swati is it possible in any way to add a tooltip feature in html. so basically on  hover of text in description i should actually see the original description which is much longer in length. the original description i will get in the java script functiononly

Comment: yes you can try with [boostrap tooltip](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/tooltips/) or just use `readmore or less` text to show more or less text whenever divs is clicked.